# How to use cloud sync and keep privacy?

Tags: google, privacy, online-storage

So you can block ads that track your every movement on the net. However, this is useless, because if you're signed in to Google Chrome for sync, they can still track your every movement through the browser. What's more if you use Android or Chrome OS, they can track your every action even outside the browser.

How can I use cloud sync for my data, so that I do not lose it and have easy access to it, and ensure at the same time that I'm not being spied upon by a corporation who may give this information to government who thus will have power over me and can make me their slave?

Comment: stop using internet services

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, your description and your questions **are unrelated**. You cannot compare Google tracking, any big government plot and using any online storage.

I will retain your question because it is interesting though.

You can encrypt your data before sending them to *the cloud*. Several services offer all-in-one solution like [Secret Sync described by How-To Geel](http://www.howtogeek.com/63262/sync-encrypted-files-with-dropbox-and-secretsync/).

Comment: how would i encrypt my browser history in Chrome before sending it to Google?

Comment: see [Google Help](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1181035)

Comment: yet, if you are paranoid about your personal data, don't use Chrome but an alternative browser, for instance Firefox